# how to make 'Alert' or 'Popup' at the controller

Tags: java, spring

Hello i just wanna get some advise.
My Problem is a little complicated.

summarize

1. Now, I am developing JAVA programming with SPRING FRAMEWORK.
2. client program is solution that is a kind of image viewer, (so I can't modify the code) bring some images from our NAS.
3. the problem is that the Search Condition of the solution program.
   the more NAS has images, the more User have to wait( because result list don't have paging function)
4. when the Search Condition is so rough, my Server(service) is dead (out of memory)
5. So I want to Alert or Popup to User that use the solution. (without modifying the solution.)

here is my virtual scenario.

1. user search button click(Too rough condition)
2. call @RequestMapping("/***") and go to Controller
3. Server send to user Message that your search condition is too rough and stop searching.

Is it impossible?

if it is possible, how can i solve it?

there is code in google, i adapt my code, but it does't work, because 'HttpServletResponse response' make exception.

this code is not same to my trial, just motive.
My Core Question is this!

**Is it possible that Server send to user Message without modifying client program?**

@RequestMapping("/****")

```
public String loginaction(

          @RequestParam(value="XXXX", required=true) String XXXX

        , @RequestParam(value="XXXX",required=true) String XXXX

        , HttpServletResponse response

         ) throws Exception{


    if(rough condition search){      

        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<script>alert('check your Search Condition');</script>");

        out.flush(); 

    }

    return XXXX;

}
```

Comment: So many things here. (1) You can't make a popup from AJAX; the best you can do is to return a 503 status code. (2) The whole point of Spring is not to do all of this business by hand--use a View if you're rendering HTML, and since you shouldn't here, return a POJO instead and let Spring turn it into JSON; same with reading any parameters. (3) Use Spring Security instead of reinventing your own login system. (4) Never send passwords as query parameters because they get logged and cached. (5) Avoid using `HttpServletR*` parameters in Spring MVC when you can; you nearly always can.

Comment: @bellwok, you are returning url after writing response content. That may be the reason. The return statement redirects the control to another url. Try return null in that case. Not sure, just give it a try. Assuming your client is a browser.

Comment: Create a wrapper service and redirect to the client solution only if it is not a generic search. return an Error message and catch that message and display it in alert box. is it possible to share the code on how you are making the service call?